# Reputation change without any action

Tags: support

I am SO user last time have visited my account I have seen my reputation was 111 but right now its showing me 110 & if i am not wrong there is no way to lose 1 reputation in any case. I could not understand how it could be possible.

Comment: If you go to your rep page - http://stackoverflow.com/users/2761097/pulah-nandha?tab=reputation there's a checkbox at the bottom to 'Show Removed Posts'. Does checking that make any difference?

Answer (score 11):

One of your questions was deleted.

It has a single upvote (+5) and 2 downvotes (-4). The remaining 1 reputation point was removed with the question.

Comment: thank you sir. I wasn't aware about it.